# How to check version of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, version

I want check how version of Visual studio i have in my pc, i means what version and what update for exemple visual studio 2013 update 4 or update 2, 
thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Click on <kbd>Help</kbd> > <kbd>About Microsoft Visual Studio</kbd>. You will see the version number and the update you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open VS
2. Select Help
3. Select About Microsoft Visual studio.

[Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlO9e.png)
[VS Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7yGG.png)